# Let $ \ I \ $ be the set of integers from $ \ 1 \ \ to \ \ n \ $

Tags: combinatorics

Let $ \ I \ $ be the set of integers from $ \ 1 \ \ to \ \ n \ $. Let $ \ P(I)=power \ \ set \ \ of \ \ I $. \begin{align} Denote \ \ X_{E}=\{A \in P(I) : |A|=even \} \ \ and \ \ X_{O}=\{A \in P(I): |A|=odd \}. \\ Define \ map \ f_{1 }: X_{E} \rightarrow X_{O}\ \ and \ f_{2}: X_{O} \rightarrow X_{E}  \ \ by \ \ the \ common \ \ rule  \ \ A \rightarrow A \ \Delta \ \{1\}. Show \ \ that \ \ the \ maps \ are \ Bijective.  \end{align}. $$ $$  Define the maps $ f_{1}: X_{E} \rightarrow X_{O} $ defined by $ f(A)=A \Delta \{1\} \ \ and \ f_{2}: X_{O} \rightarrow X_{E} \ by \ f_{2}(A)=A \Delta \{1\} $ . Now to show that the maps are bijective , take their composition as follows: $ f_{1} \circ f_{2} (A)=f_{1}(A \Delta \{1\})=f_{1}(A)=A \Delta \{1\}=A, \ \ \ \ \ if \ |A|=even\ \ i.e, \{1\} \notin X_{E} .$ Hence  $ f_{1} \circ f_{2}=identity $. But I am not sure  about the calculation.  **Any help please?**

Comment: I'm confused. You already defined the maps: $A \mapsto A \vartriangle \{1\}$. Do you know what the $\vartriangle$ symbol means in this context?

Comment: yes the symbol is symmetric difference. $ A \Delta \{1\}=(A \setminus \{1\} ) \cup (\{1\} \setminus A) =A \setminus \{1\} \cup \phi =A \setminus \{1\}$

Comment: Great, and that's your map from $X_E \to X_O$ and $X_O \to X_E$. Can you clarify what you're trying to ask?

Comment: I want to show that these maps are bijective or the sets $ X_{E} \ and \ X_{O} $ are of same cardinality.

Comment: I see. When you said "Any help defining the maps only" I thought you meant that you only wanted help defining the maps, not actually showing that they are bijections. To show that they are bijections, it suffices to show that the composition (in both directions) is the identity map on $X_E$ and $X_O$.

Comment: but if $ \{1\} $ \Notin A $ , then how can you define the maps ?

Comment: You still define it with $A \vartriangle \{1\}$. If $1$ is not an element of $A$, then $A \vartriangle \{1\}$ = $A \cup \{1\}$. I suggest you review the definition of symmetric difference of two sets.

Comment: How to show that their composition in either direction is Identity? little more help

Comment: This discussion is getting a bit long for the comments. I suggest you edit your main post showing what you've tried so far.

Comment: yes , I showed my work.  help me at that point

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are more elegant solutions, but you can directly compute your statement by using the definition of $f_1$ and $f_2$ and some elementary set equation.

You have just to compute $f_1\circ f_2(A)=A$ for all $A\in X_O$ and $f_2\circ f_1(B)=B$ for all $B\in X_E$.

Consider $A\in X_O$. Then you compute
\begin{align}
f_1(f_2(A))&=f_1((A\setminus\{1\})\cup(\{1\}\setminus A))\\
&=(((A\setminus\{1\})\cup(\{1\}\setminus A))\setminus\{1\})\cup(\{1\}\setminus((A\setminus\{1\})\cup(\{1\}\setminus A)))
\end{align}
Now you have to simplify using elementary set equations
\begin{align}
((A\setminus\{1\})\cup(\{1\}\setminus A))\setminus\{1\}&=((A\setminus\{1\})\setminus\{1\})\cup((\{1\}\setminus A)\setminus\{1\})\\
&=(A\setminus \{1\})\cup\emptyset=A\setminus \{1\}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(\{1\}\setminus((A\setminus\{1\})\cup(\{1\}\setminus A)))&=(\{1\}\setminus(A\setminus\{1\}))\cap(\{1\}\setminus (\{1\}\setminus A))\\
&=\{1\}\cap(\{1\}\cap A)=\{1\}\cap A.
\end{align}
Together we get
$$
f_1(f_2(A))=(A\setminus\{1\})\cup(\{1\}\cap A)=A.
$$
Since the symmetric definition of $f_1$ and $f_2$ we also got $f_2\circ f_1(B)=B$ for $B\in X_E$.

Comment: It's much easier to just show directly that $A \vartriangle \{1\} = A \cup \{1\}$ if $1 \notin A$ and $A \vartriangle \{1\} = A \setminus \{1\}$ if $1 \in A$. This makes it very clear that $(A \vartriangle \{1\}) \vartriangle \{1\} = A$ for all $A$.

Comment: Like I mentioned, there is a more elegant way, i.e. consider the cases $1\in A$ and $1\notin A$ like you wrote. :-)